# Mysql set default value to a json type column

Tags: mysql, sql, json, create-table, alter-table

I heard that mysql version prior to 8.0.13 accept default value for json type column, so I using the cmd:

```
ALTER TABLE templates CHANGE COLUMN values JSON NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}' ;
```

but receive error:

```
Error Code: 1101. BLOB, TEXT, GEOMETRY or JSON column 'values' can't have a default value
```

So how do I fix it?

I'm using mysql version 8.0.19 and client tool Workbench

Answer (score 66, accepted):

**From version 8.0.13 onwards**, the [documentation says](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html#data-type-defaults.html#data-type-defaults-explicit) (emphasis is mine):

> The `BLOB`, `TEXT`, `GEOMETRY`, **and `JSON` data types can be assigned a default value** only if the value is written as an expression, even if the expression value is a literal.

You can make your default an expression by surrounding the literal value with parentheses:

```
ALTER TABLE templates CHANGE COLUMN values JSON NOT NULL DEFAULT ('{}') ;
```

Or:

```
ALTER TABLE templates CHANGE COLUMN values JSON NOT NULL DEFAULT (JSON_OBJECT()) ;
```

---

**Prior to version 8.0.13 of MySQL**, it was not possible to set a default value on a JSON column, as the 8.0 documentation points out [a few paragraphs later](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html#data-type-defaults-explicit-old) :

> The  `BLOB`, `TEXT`, `GEOMETRY`, and `JSON` data types cannot be assigned a default value.

Comment: Note that this only works as of version 8.0.13 - before, [e.g. in version 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html#data-types-defaults-explicit), defaults for JSON are not possible. ("The BLOB, TEXT, GEOMETRY, and JSON data types cannot be assigned a default value.")

Comment: should have read the comment.  if you try this in **Aurora MySQL 5.7** the result is error message: `BLOB, TEXT, GEOMETRY or JSON column 'your_col_name' can't have a default value. (Error #1101)`

Comment: Actually, I have the same error on mysql 8.0.28 as well (can't have a default value #1011)

Answer (score 14):

According to the laravel docs:

```
$table->json('movies')->default(new Expression('(JSON_ARRAY())'));
```

> The default modifier accepts a value or an Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression instance. Using an Expression instance will prevent Laravel from wrapping the value in quotes and allow you to use database specific functions. One situation where this is particularly useful is when you need to assign default values to JSON columns

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#default-expressions

Answer (score 5):

MySql syntax is a bit different than Oracle/Postgres, hence to make say JSON_Array as default, the query would be -

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER column_name SET DEFAULT (JSON_ARRAY());
```

Further reference [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mysql-cookbook/0596001452/ch08s05.html)